# Include parent padding in selected state of TextView

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, textview, selecteditem

I have a `RelativeLayout` with padding and a `TextView` child.  When the `TextView` is selected, I want the highlighted area to extend to include the padding of the parent, so that the entire `RelativeLayout` is highlighted.

`main.xml`

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/myback"
        />
```

`myback.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/gray" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/gray" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/gray" />
</selector>
```

`MyActivity.java`

```
package com.example.TextViewPadding;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have this behaviour, you need to add your padding to the `TextView` instead of the `RelativeLayout` Keep the padding on the parent at 0.